# How do I associate custom made virtual objects to link to relational objects working like Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `CustomerDetails` and a `CustomerAddress` object. The constructors are as follow:

```
public class CustomerDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public int AddressID { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerAddress customerAddress { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerDetails> CustomerDetails { get; set; }
}
```

I have copied these two constructors from generated code of Entity Framework.

I have used `SqlDataReader` to populate the customer list and address list

```
List<CustomerDetails> customers = new List<CustomerDetails>();
List<CustomerAddress> addresses = new List<CustomerAddress>();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customerdetails", con);

using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        CustomerDetails customer = new CustomerDetails
                    {
                        CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CustomerID"]),
                        AddressID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["AddressID"]),
                        CustomerName = rdr["CustomerName"].ToString()
                    };
        customers.Add(customer);
    }
}

cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CustomerAddress", con);

using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        CustomerAddress address = new CustomerAddress
                    {
                        AddressID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["AddressID"]),
                        Address = rdr["Address"].ToString()
                    };
                    addresses.Add(address);
    }
}
```

When I try to bind data using LINQ to display customer's address, it doesn't work as intended.

```
GridView1.DataSource = from c in customers
                       select new { c.CustomerName, c.customerAddress.AddressID};
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I knew it's going to happen. But what's the trick to make the virtual objects linking to the relational object so that the reference will work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to populate the virtual properties yourself, or   just remove them and use an inner join in your query.

```
// populate
For Each CustomerDetail from db        
    IF CustomerDetail.AddressId NOT IN addresses
       Fetch CustomerAddress from Db
       addresses.Add(CustomerAddress )
    ELSE
       FETCH CustomerAddress from addresses
    END
    CustomerDetail.customerAddress = CustomerAddress
    CustomerAddress.CustomerDetails.Add(CustomerDetail)
    customers.Add(CustomerDetail)


//inner join
from c in customers
      join a in addresses on c.AddressID equals a.AddressID
      select new { c.CustomerName, a.Address}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure where does this code I should put. Can you give me some referrence of this implementation?

Comment: I cannot find this part of implimentation in the code generated by Entity Framework (scafforlding). How do they achieve it? That's amazing

Comment: FYI I'm not a 100% expert and not studied the EF implementation in detail.  EF does clever stuff and dynamically generates and runs SQL behind the scenes when you access the virtual properties etc..  You can get a view of what's EF does by tracing the database or using a tool like LinqPad.  
Note: The pseudo code I suggest is to replace your population code example.
I'm interested to see if you get anymore more knowledgeable answers, and hopefully learn something new.